# Find Gridview inside listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having gridview in template field of listview. i get the gridview if i do the following

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
   {
        ListViewDataItem item = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        GridView grdview = (GridView)item.FindControl("GridView1");
   }
}
```

but the problem is this i want to make this gridview editable so that i can edit the fields from gridview.for that i have to find this gridview for that i don't know what to do . i need help.. Thanks in advance to friends who helped me already n i expected the same this time.

Comment: OK for a starter add vowels to your words.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in lots of ways to update gridview
1.u can set datasource or
2. grab corresponding control in gridview and set values and bind it

```
GridView grdview = (GridView)item.FindControl("GridView1");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();//creating datatable
dt.Columns.Add("Columnname");//creating column name 
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Columnname"] = "hello";//enter value
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
grdView.DataSource = dt;//sets the datasource to gridview 
grdView.DataBind();//this call binds datasource dt to your gridiview
```

Or grab control to specified field through **e.Row.FindControl**
For example

```
Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Name");
lbl.text="s";//set values
```

if not clear visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277772/bind-data-to-gridview-instance-inside-listview-itemdatabound)

Comment: my gridview is inside listview and i want to do editing in this gridview how is it possible????